# How can I transition a site from using the Beta Tester plugin to a "normal" install?

Tags: database, upgrade

I'm currently using the [WordPress Beta Tester](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/) plugin on a site. Is there a "best" way to transition the site to a "normal" WordPress install? The plugin includes this notice:

> Please note: Once you have switched
>   your blog to one of these beta
>   versions of software it will not
>   always be possible to downgrade as the
>   database structure maybe updated
>   during the development of a major
>   release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one way is to simply manually upload the wp-admin and wp-includes directories, as the [normal upgrade instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Step_1%3a_Replace_WordPress_files) state. I did this, and it worked. I'm still curious if there's a better way, to avoid any database issues.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would just upload the files as normal or delete the plugin. I personally dont use the plugin. And as far as db update and changes i dont think there is much change or any change in the db. Also i would not advise using the beta as a live site. It may seem stable but there are always exploits that can be found and since we are about a month out for the official it is best to just wait.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be simply to deactivate the Plugin, and then update to the final-release version as per normal.

Alternately, if you're using the bleeding-edge nightlies, just switch to stable, and then update at the next stable.

But if you need to downgrade? Yeah, you might not be able to do that. If you have a site that you might potentially need to downgrade, *don't run unstable versions on it in the first place*.